# Adding a new column with apply and gregexpr

Tags: r

I have one main list with several sub-lists inside that contains many data.frames.
See example below :

```
sublist1 <- list(data.frame('Position' = c(1,2,3), 'Color' = c("black-white-
silver-red","black-white-red","black-white")),
             data.frame('Position' = c(1,2,3), 'Color' = c("black-white-
pink-gold-red","black-white","black")) )

sublist2 <- list(data.frame('Position' = c(1,2,3), 'Color' = c("black-
silver-red","black-white-red","white")),
             data.frame('Position' = c(1,2,3), 'Color' = c("pink-gold-
red","black-white","black-white")) )

mainList <- list(sublist1, sublist2)
```

I am trying to add a new column to each data.frame called 'Color_Count' that will return the number of different colors for each row of the data.frame. Ideally the output would look like this:

```
> mainList
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
Position                  Color Color_Count
1        1 black-white-silver-red           4
2        2        black-white-red           3
3        3            black-white           2

[[1]][[2]]
Position                     Color Color_Count
1        1 black-white-pink-gold-red           5
2        2               black-white           2
3        3                     black           1
....
```

I have tried to use the gregexpr function as well as lapply but the output never looks like what I want.

I would really appreciate some help here.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: you have to extract all "-" then count the "-" and add 1 to it. Useful functions like `nchar` and `gsub("[^-]","",...)` will lead you in a good direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we can assume that each color is separated by a dash "-" we can simply count the number of dashes in the Color column and add 1:

```
foo <- function(lst, col) {
  lapply(lst, function(x) 
    if(!is.data.frame(x)) foo(x, col) 
    else transform(x, ColorCount = stringr::str_count(x[[col]], "-")+1))}

foo(mainList, "Color")

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#  Position                    Color ColorCount
#1        1 black-white-\nsilver-red          4
#2        2          black-white-red          3
#3        3              black-white          2
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#  Position Color                     ColorCount
#1        1 black-white-pink-gold-red          5
#2        2 black-white                        2
#3        3 black                              1
#...
```

I'm using the `stringr` library to compute the counts but you can use base R or stringi or other approaches too.

I've built `foo` as a recursive function because you have a list of lists and we only want to work on the data.frames at the inner most list.

Comment: Very nice although to be totally responsive to the question the solution should use `gregexpr` -- `else transform(x, ColorCount = lengths(gregexpr("-", Color))+1))}`

Comment: maybe one of the moments for `rapply` with `how="list"`

Comment: @AndreElrico `rapply` operates on non-list nodes and data frames are list nodes so I don't think `rapply` can work here.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks, that base approach is a valuable add-on

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I just noticed though that it seems to be incorrect for 1-Color (=no dash) cases because the result is not zero lenght but still 1 (specifically it is -1)

Comment: @docendodiscimus, Good point.  Paste "-" onto `Color` instead of adding 1: `else transform(x, ColorCount = lengths(gregexpr("-", paste(Color, "-")))))}`

Comment: @docendodiscimus you are right. I can only access the indiv. cols!

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Quick question : could you explain to me why do we have to provide  ' col' variable in the function while we never use it ?

Comment: @ThomasAMET, uh, good point. That's actually a mistake. You can either drop it from the function definition or change the code to `stringr::str_count(x[[col]], "-")`

Comment: @docendodiscimus ! thank you a lot for your help.
I have one additional question... what would have been the syntax to reach the sub-element of the 'mainlist' assuming that it was not data.frame but vector (or list ) ?

Comment: @ThomasAMET, that's a little difficult to answer without a concrete example. Generally, you wouldn't test for `is.data.frame(...)` if you're looking for a simple vector, for example. In that case you might be able to use `rapply` (which is recursive) instead of building a recursive function yourself. And of course you would not be operating on a column but on the list element itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Approach:** Extract nested lists into single tidy data frame

This method requires a function from the `data.table` package called `rbindlist()` and the `dplyr` package

```
df <- lapply(mainList, rbindlist, idcol = "sub.id") %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "id") %>% 
  mutate(
    Color = stringi::stri_replace_all(Color, "", regex = "\\n|\\s"),
    Color_Count = stringi::stri_count(Color, regex = "-") + 1
  )
```

What I find great about `rbindlist()` is that it allows you to designate IDs as you unnest the nested data frames.

The output should look like this:

```
head(df)
  id sub.id Position                     Color Color_Count
#  1      1        1    black-white-silver-red           4
#  1      1        2           black-white-red           3
#  1      1        3               black-white           2
#  1      2        1 black-white-pink-gold-red           5
#  1      2        2               black-white           2
#  1      2        3                     black           1
```